# What is the difference between Differential of a map and Parallel transportation?

Tags: differential-geometry

If $\gamma$ is a closed geodesic in $M$ with $p=c(0)=c(1)$. We have two maps, namely first is the differential of the action of the class $[c]\in \pi_1(M, p)$ on the tangent space $T_p(\tilde{M})$, where $p$ is a lift of $p$ to the universal cover. Then we can measure how the action 'rotates' the tangent vectors in $T_p(\tilde{M})$ by parallel transport them to $T_{\tilde{C(1)}}\tilde{M}$, where $\tilde{C(1)}$ is the lift of the $p$ along the geodesic $c$. This is the view in the universal cover.

Another view is we can see how the rotations looks like purely in $M$, i.e. we can use the parallel transportation along the geodesic $c$ to map $T_p(M)$ to $T_p(M)$.

My question is: Are these two point of view the same? (The second view does not involve the differential of map, just pure parallel transport only. However the first one involve both.)

Second question is: Are they the same if we replace the closed geodesic by close geodesic loop?

My guess for both questions are "yes", but I confused and didn't find any reference taking about these two maps.